# Bool value always gets outputted to True only

Tags: c#, .net

I am having the following code snippet where I pass a value either `True` or `False` through the `PropertyValue` parameter in the method declaration.

```
public void SetTaskInstance(String PropertyName, String PropertyValue, int row)
{
    bool bValue;
    try
    {
        PropertyName = PropertyName.ToUpper();
        switch (PropertyName)
        {
            case "BYPASSRULESENGINE":
                m_tInstance.byPassRulesEngine =            
                   System.Boolean.TryParse(PropertyValue.ToString(), out bValue);
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking method");
    }
}
```

If I pass `True`, then `True` is outputted. However if I pass `False`, the parameter `False` is passed through the code but once the break statement is reached and when I hover my mouse over `m_tInstance.ByPassRulesEngine`, I see that the bool value has become `True` almost magically. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Where is `True` output? I see you set `m_tInstance.byPassRulesEngine` to the return value of `TryParse` but that will always be true if the parse is successful, regardless of the parsed value. This function doesen't ouput anything or do anything with `bValue` so its hard to see the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The return value of TryParse indicates if the parse was successful. And of course, the value "false" or "False" is valid, so TryParse would return true. The parsed value itself is written into the `out bValue` parameter.

Change the line

```
m_tInstance.byPassRulesEngine = System.Boolean.TryParse(PropertyValue.ToString(), out bValue);
```

to

```
bool parseSuccessful = System.Boolean.TryParse(PropertyValue.ToString(), out bValue);
if (parseSuccessful)
{
    m_tInstance.byPassRulesEngine = bValue;
}
```

All TryParse methods behave that way. So read the documentation of TryParse on MSDN here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain why you always receive a true value:

The function `System.Boolean.TryParse` returns true, if it can successfully do the conversion, from a String to a Boolean.

So in your example it will always be true.

Carsten Schütte has already given the solution code.

Comment: @Carsten Schütte I was so ready to answer this one, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse.aspx)
the result of the conversion is stored in Output variable (your `bValue`)

> When this method returns, if the conversion succeeded, contains true
>   if value is equivalent to Boolean.TrueString or false if value is
>   equivalent to FalseString. If the conversion failed, contains false.
>   The conversion fails if value is null or is not equivalent to the
>   value of either the TrueString or FalseString field.